# Storing a JSON response from an API to a CSV file

Tags: python, json, api, csv

I’m trying to write a python script that sends a query to TweetSentiments.com API.

The idea is that it will perform like this –

Reads CSV tweet file > construct query from tweet file > Interrogates API > format JSON response > write API results to CSV file.

So far I’ve come up with this –

```
import csv
import urllib
import simplejson as json
import os

Tweets=[] ## Creates empty list to store tweets.

TweetWriter = csv.writer(open('test.csv', 'w'), dialect='excel', delimiter=' ',quotechar='|')
TweetReader = csv.reader(open("C:\StoredTweets.csv", "r"))

for row in TweetReader:

    #TweetList.append(rows)
    Tweets.append({ 'tweet': row[0], 'date': row[1] }) ## Stores from CSV in list.

for rows in Tweets:


    #print TweetList

    data = urllib.urlencode({'Tweet': row[0], 'Date': row[1]}) ##Takes Tweet and date to construct query.

    #print data

    API_request = urllib.urlopen("http://data.tweetsentiments.com:8080/api/analyze.json?q=", data) ## Adds query to end of URL and queries API

    result = json.load(API_request('{"sentiment":}') ## "Sentiment": is a heading in the JSON response

    TweetWriter.writerow(result) ## Writes API Response to CSV file.
```

I’m having trouble decoding the json. I’m confused with the json.load part … should I be referring to a heading in the json response and then trying to store it to a variable? Meaning that I can write this to a CSV file?

The response I get from the API is –

```
{"sentiment":{"value":1,"name":"Positive"}}
```

So I figure referring to “Sentiment” would store the whole reply.

Sorry, I’m just getting really confused. Read so many different forum posts and tutorials.

Your advice and help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: first you need to deserialize the json [json encoder - decoder](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) then you will be able to save it into a csv file. [csv ni python](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)

Comment: When I print the API-request variable I get - "<addinfourl at 14920600 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0X00E028FO>>". I assume this is what you mean needing deserialized?  By changing "result = json.load(API_request('{"sentiment":}')" to simply "result = json.load(API_request)"I am told “simplejson.decoder.JSONDecodeError: NO JSON  objectcould be decoded: line 1 column o <char 0>

Comment: {"sentiment":{"value":1,"name":"Positive"}} <== that's your json. and this is what you need to deserialize.

Comment: Yes – and from my query to the API this json should now be stored in API_request? So then using json.load should deserialize the response?

Comment: convert the json respons without the header. And convert it to an object (with 2 properties (values and name)).

Comment: I think there's also another bug in your code.  Pretty sure you should be doing `data = urllib.urlencode(rows)`.  Right now, your first loop there is a throw away, and you will just end up sending the last tweet in the csv as many times as there are rows in the file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert JSON to CSV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976345/convert-json-to-csv)